# Redirect all urls except one in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, drupal

I am trying to redirect all URLs on my site (let's call it [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com)) except one in my .htaccess file. I currently have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my/page$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site2.com [R=302,L]
```

With the above, all requests to [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) are redirected to [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com), including the one that I do **not** want to redirect.

After some experimentation, I have found that the following works to redirect only a specific page:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my/page$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site2.com [R=302,L]
```

I'm not sure why the ! operator isn't working as I expect. Perhaps there is an error in my regex?

Some additional bit of information. This is a Drupal site running on a dedicated cPanel host. But I have been sure to put this new redirect rewrite rule before all the other Drupal-specific rewrite rules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it better to first create a condition for that single page and because it doen't match for the other pages, have another one for the rest?

Comment: Your first version is correct, it works (assuming the requested URL actually _is_ `/my/page`). Question is why it does not work _in your specific case_ ... First guess: you are looking at cached results from earlier attempts?

Comment: @onlineThomas - I am certainly open to taking a different approach. If you could present your idea in more detail as an answer I would be happy to try it.

Comment: @arkascha - I have been sure to clear the cache and I have triple checked that the urls are correct. I am seeing www.site1.com/my/page getting redirected, along with all others.

Comment: Then I suggest you enable rewrite logging inside your http server to be able to observe the steps taken inside your rewriting engine. The documentation explains how to do that.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion. However in the interest of time, I chose to just redirect certain pages, instead of all pages except one.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index.php) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,QSA,L,END]
```

You need to make sure you exclude the page you redirect to from you list of possible url that get redirected(to avoid the loop) and then you can add more before the RewriteRule.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index.php) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index_new.php) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,QSA,L,END]

Comment: This is what the OP tries to do and it does not work according to him. What point is there in telling him he has to do what he indeed tries to do? Especially using an example which is inconsistent in itself and does not match the details in the answer.

Comment: He does not negate  the destination site2 and then he ends up redirecting site2 to site2 and he does not want that. It is a common mistake in .htaccess redirecting you always have to negate the destination to avoid going in a loop.

Comment: Maybe you should read the question again. All of it.